# Event ColumnHeaderMouseClick Cannot be found

Tags: vb.net, sorting, gridview, click, mouseevent

I am loading some data into a GridView in vb, and need to make the columns sortable. The default sorting properties do not work, and The program can't find the ColumnHeaderClickEvent.

I am loading my table data using:

```
        Using db = DBConnect()
        db.CommandText = $"Select * FROM tblStudySummary "
        GridView1.DataSource = (ReportQueryObject.BuildReportDataTable(db.GetDataSet))
        GridView1.DataBind()


        End Using
```

I am attempting to get the column header name when the user clicks on it, I could then sort the data using SQL.

```
        Private Sub HeaderClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As                   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles                              GridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Dim col_index = e.ColumnIndex
    Dim col_name = GridView1.Columns(col_index).Name
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Index={0}, Name={1}", col_index,
    col_name))
    End Sub
```

I am really at a loss as to what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've also tried casting the dataSource to an SQLdataSource but to no avail. not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` is a member of the `DataGridView` class, which is a WinForms control. It has nothing to do with the Web Forms `GridView`. It took me seconds to find that out by [searching the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/?term=ColumnHeaderMouseClick). You should NEVER be asking a question here without consulting the relevant documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you gonna have to read this document to do it in the proper way... I can't help any further. I work on Desktops apps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-sort-a-gridview-column-when-a-header-is-clicked?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I went in the wrong direction in my "before edit" response.

It can be accesed with:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
```

I guess you are merging the gridview with the datatable loaded.
In datatables you can acces to the columnname with `Datatable.Columns(e.columnindex).ColumnName`

I usually bind the datatable to a bindingsource and this bindingsource to the datagridview. So you can filter the bindingsource and the bindingsource will upgrade all the places where it is showed.

```
Dim BS as New BindingSource
BS.Datasource = Datatable
Datagridview.Datasource = BS
```